# Check from where an ASP.Net page in my application was opened?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Searched everywhere but couldn't find anything.

My question is: is it possible to programmatically determine the address of the site from where a page in my ASP.Net application was opened (either from client code or server code)?

Suppose i have a big job board application, some of the jobs are listed in Google. How can one tell if the page was opened directly from the application, or from an external source like search engines/ etc (i.e. did someone click a link in Google and got here?).

Thanks!

Comment: You can use google analytics (http://www.google.com/analytics/) for this purpose, what you just have to do is to create a google account and paste the javascript, which you will get from g-analytics website, in your aspx pages...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for

```
Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

Comment: Allright this works! i'll accept your answer as soon as possible! Thanks! Also I've found that Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri can be used for the same purpose as well

Comment: @user - great, glad to help, but be aware its sometimes unreliable. Search Google for discussions on when/how/why.